# getServerSideProps being called twice and returning object on second call

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a next.js app. One of the pages is calling getServerSideProps twice. On the second call, it is returning a string of "[object, Object]" on the second call. This is obviously causing an error when the page tries to load.

This just started and I have no idea how to diagnose the issue. The page takes in two URL arguments. I output those to the console in the getServerSideProps function as shown below. On the first call, the two properties are as input. On the second call the first one is fine, but the second is "[object Object]".

Here is the page ...

```
// React and Next items
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

// Bootstrap items
import { Container, Row, Col } from "react-bootstrap";

// My components
import Layout from "../../../components/layout";
import TagInfo from "./TagInfo";
import TagList from "../../../components/TagList";
import ArticleLine from "../../../components/ArticleLine";

// API functions
import { getFullTagData } from "../../../utils/api/tag";
import { updateTag } from "../../../utils/api/tag";

// Utility functions
import {
  checkChildTagProperties,
  syncCumulativeValues,
} from "../../../utils/tags";
import { updateCumulative } from "../../../utils/api/cumulative";
import { setLatestItems } from "../../../utils/tagLatestItems";

// Contexts
import { useUser } from "../../../Contexts/UserContext";

const Tag = ({ thisTag, childTags, childItems, cumulatives }) => {
  const userData = useUser();
  const [stateTag, setStateTag] = useState(thisTag);
  const [stateTags, setStateTags] = useState(childTags);
  const [stateItems, setStateItems] = useState(childItems);

  const addChildItem = (newItem) => {
    setStateItems([...stateItems, newItem]);
    setLatestItems(stateTag, newItem, stateTag.parent_tag_id);
  };

  const addChildTag = (newTag) => {
    setStateTags([...stateTags, newTag]);
  };

  const handleShowEditArticle = (status, newArticle) => {
    setCurrentArticle(newArticle);
    setShowEditArticle(status);
  };

  const handleShowDeleteItem = (status, item) => {
    setCurrentArticle(item);
    setShowDeleteItem(status);
  };

  // When the page loads, run code to check the child tag properties
  useEffect(() => {
    checkChildTagProperties(stateTag, stateTags, updateTag);
    syncCumulativeValues(
      stateTag,
      stateTags,
      stateItems,
      cumulatives,
      updateTag,
      updateCumulative
    );
    setLatestItems(stateTag.id, stateItems, stateTag.parent_tag_id);
  }, []);

  return (
    <Layout>
      <Container>
        <Row>
          <Col xs={{ span: 12 }} md={{ span: 10, offset: 1 }}>
            <TagInfo
              tag={stateTag}
              cumulatives={cumulatives}
              userData={userData || {}}
              addChildItem={addChildItem}
              addChildTag={addChildTag}
              setThisTag={setStateTag}
            />

            <Row className="accent-top">
              <Col className="mt-3">
                {stateTags.length > 0 && <TagList tags={stateTags} />}
              </Col>
            </Row>
            <Row>
              <Col className="mt-3">
                {stateItems
                  .sort((a, b) =>
                    a.itemDate < b.item_date
                      ? 1
                      : b.itemDate < a.itemDate
                      ? -1
                      : 0
                  )
                  .map((article, i) => (
                    <ArticleLine
                      article={article}
                      parentTag={stateTag}
                      key={`article${i}`}
                      handleShowEditArticle={handleShowEditArticle}
                      handleShowDeleteItem={handleShowDeleteItem}
                    />
                  ))}
              </Col>
            </Row>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Container>
    </Layout>
  );
};

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const { pTagId, tagId } = context.params;

  console.log(context.params);

  if (pTagId && tagId && tagId !== "[object Object]") {
    const response = await getFullTagData(pTagId, tagId);
    const thisTag = await response[0].json();
    const childTags = await response[1].json();
    const childItems = await response[2].json();
    const cumulatives = await response[3].json();
    return {
      props: {
        thisTag,
        childTags: childTags.Items || [],
        childItems: childItems.Items || [],
        cumulatives: cumulatives.Items || [],
      },
    };
  } else {
    return {};
  }
}

export default Tag;
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I found this discussion:

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/13064

There was an error with an image that was causing this. I don't really grasp the connection, but it seems that a bad image URL causes a double loud with faulty URL data.